# how to enter user_code in verification_url for google drive api access token without a browser

Tags: http, curl, google-drive-api, libcurl

I'm developing a low-end internet connected electronic device. 
So i don't have a real browser in my system.

I can use Google drive API properly using curl library in the system. 
But access_token became useless after the expire duration normally, then I'm creating a new `user_code` using my `client_id` and using the code in verification url to get a new `access_code`. Unfortunately second phase of this process requires a web browser.

Google Drive API's documentation says "If your application requires offline access, the first time your app exchanges the authorization code, it also receives a refresh token that it uses to receive a new access token after a previous token has expired." but i want to use refresh token.

Is there a way getting Google API's `access_key` without entering `user_code` through browser? Can I open verification link and enter `user_code` programmatically?